# Create Unique Relationship is taking much amount of time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

```
START names = node(*),
  target=node:node_auto_index(target_name="TARGET_1")
MATCH names 
WHERE NOT names-[:contains]->() 
  AND HAS (names.age)
  AND (names.qualification =~ ".*(?i)B.TECH.*$" 
    OR names.qualification =~ ".*(?i)B.E.*$") 
CREATE UNIQUE (names)-[r:contains{type:"declared"}]->(target)
RETURN names.name,names,names.qualification
```

Iam consisting of nearly 1,80,000 names nodes, i had iterated the above process to create unique relationships above 100 times by changing the target. its taking too much amount of time.How can i resolve it..

i build the query with java and iterated.iam using neo4j 2.0.0.5 and java 1.7 .

Answer (score 2):

I edited your cypher query because I think I understand it, but I can barely read the rest of your question. If you edit it with white spaces and punctuation it might be easier to understand what you are trying to do. Until then, here are some thoughts about your query being slow.

1. You bind all the nodes in the graph, that's typically pretty slow.
2. You bind all the nodes in the graph twice. First you bind universally in your start clause: `names=node(*)`, and then you bind universally in your match clause: `MATCH names`, and only then you limit your pattern. I don't quite know what the Cypher engine makes of this (possibly it gets a migraine and goes off to make a pot of coffee). It's unnecessary, you can at least drop the `names=node(*)` from your start clause. Or drop the match clause, I suppose that could work too, since you don't really do anything there, and you will still need a start clause for as long as you use legacy indexing.
3. You are using Neo4j 2.x, but you use legacy indexing instead of labels, at least in this query. Without knowing your data and model it's hard to know what the difference would be for performance, but it would certainly make it much easier to write (and read) your queries. So, that's a different kind of slow. It's likely that if you had labels and label indices, the query performance would improve.

So, first try removing one of the universal bindings of nodes, then use the 2.x [schema](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-schema.html) tools to structure your data. You should be able to write queries like

```
MATCH target:Target
WHERE target.target_name="TARGET_1"
WITH target
MATCH names:Name
WHERE NOT names-[:contains]->() 
  AND HAS (names.age)
  AND (names.qualification =~ ".*(?i)B.TECH.*$" 
    OR names.qualification =~ ".*(?i)B.E.*$") 
CREATE UNIQUE (names)-[r:contains{type:"declared"}]->(target)
RETURN names.name,names,names.qualification
```

I have no idea if such a query would be fast on your data, however. If you put the "Name" label on all your nodes, then `MATCH names:Name` will still bind all nodes in the database, so it'll probably still be slow.

P.S. The relationships you create have a `TYPE` called `contains`, and you give them a property called `type` with value `declared`. Maybe you have a good reason, but that's potentially very confusing.

**Edit:**
Reading through your question and my answer again I no longer think that I understand even your cypher query. (Why are you returning both the bound nodes and properties of those nodes?) Please consider posting sample data on [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org) and explain in more detail what your model looks like and what you are trying to do. Let me know if my answer meets your question at all or I'll consider removing it.

Comment: Iam a beginner to the neo4j, i'm just little confused with Indexing and Lables..Your answer is good.After reading your answer iam having a problem with Index,I had refered the links of Neo4j for Indexing. I had already used csv Importer to import the nodes and relations, How to give indexing ther..